# How do I disable requiring a password for rebooting or shutting down

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, raspbian-jessie

I have noticed that after some update, the Pi now requires a password for rebooting or shutting down. I have a Pi 3 and I am accessing my Pi via VNC and doing the shutdown/reboot from the GUI (not the command line), if that makes any difference.

Is there any setting I can update to disable this password requirement for reboot/shutdown?

---

#### Update

After tlhIngan's post, I did some more experimenting and it is as if the GUI for shutting down the computer is no longer prefixing `shutdown` or `reboot` with `sudo`. Next, I opened up a terminal and entered `reboot` (no `sudo` and I get the same password dialog). I may need to file a bug report for this...

[image: Pi Reboot Password]

Comment: If they've changed something this way it is most likely apparent in `/etc/sudoers` or a file in `/etc/sudoers.d` if it exists -- if not it's some dunderheaded functionality added to the GUI interface and you will not be able to modify it.

Comment: I've had this same problem recently. After reinstalling Raspbian it disappeared for a week or so, but today it started happening again.

Comment: After doing some testing, I figured out that this only happens when I connect to my Pi remotely using VNC. I also have to enter a password to mount and eject a USB flash drive. I wonder if this is related to something I noticed in the [release notes](http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/release_notes.txt) for the latest version of Raspbian (4.4): "Removed sudo from shutdown options"

Answer (score 1):

Raspbian comes configured by default to not require passwords for sudo commands from user pi. If you are using a different user account or if this no-password requirement has been changed by an update, [here's](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7133/how-to-change-pi-sudo-permissions) how to change it back.

Comment: I added some new information and clarifications to my original post.