# How do I grant sudo privileges to an existing user?

Tags: pi-3, sudo, root, user

I am using vnc viewer on Windows 10.

user: **pi**

I am lost, please help.

***What I Have Tried:***

*sudo chmod 777 **

**also ..**

*sudo nano /etc/sudoers*

adding the following line just like "root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL" was written;-

*pi ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL*

(Restarted the device after the changes OF COURSE.)

Comment: What is your operating system and version? Maybe related: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/7137/78211

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo adduser <username> sudo`